# load a url after a specific amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a single url that I need to open it after a specific amount of time.

I think this can be done using js/jquery and I see it working like this: I open the page created with the js code inside and the url loads automatic in a new tab and after 5 minutes this same url is opened in a new tab or in the same tab that was previously opened. 
It's a trick I am working on and the problem is that I don't know much in js/jquery that's why I need your help.

You might ask me: Hey, this code will open a new tab each 5 minutes so you'll have a lot of them running, are you sure you need this?.. and I say yes, that's what I need, a new tab for a single url each 5 minutes.

Thanks.

Comment: have nothing to do with users, this is for my local browser only, it's not for web development. that's why I said: "it's a trick I am working on". Take care.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `setTimeout()` which will wait a specified amount of time (ms) then execute the declared function.

Example:

```
setTimeout(openUrl, 5000); // Wait 5 seconds

function openUrl(){

   window.open('http://google.com');

}
```

To repeat an action on a timer you can use `setInterval()`

```
setInterval(openUrl, 5000);
```

Comment: You are doing a `setTimeout` on `undefined`. You mean `setTimeout(openUrl, 5000);`

Comment: This will be blocked by a pop-up blocker because it's not a user-driven event.

Comment: Much better to not use quotes (which forces the use of eval) with `setTimeout()`.  You can just use `setTimeout(openUrl, 5000);`.

Comment: it works once, after 5 seconds it open the window, but after that it stops, how to make it continously open that url, or let say after 5 sec the url is opened in a new window and then do a refresh on this page with js in it so it will count again 5 seconds.

Comment: AlienWebguy - popupblocker can be easy disabled. I need this page only on my local, nothing to do with users.

Comment: Then you can use `setInterval(openUrl, 5000);`

Comment: 5 minutes would be `setInterval(openUrl, 1000*60*5);`

Answer (score 1):

check out the setTimeout and setInterval methods for JS

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

You need to call settimeout inside openUrl again to repeat it endlessly