# how to open new window after 5 seconds using java script

Tags: javascript

In my website, I need to open the page automatically after 5 seconds, I am using the following code, but my browser is showing POP-UP BLOCKED. Please let me know the solution for my query. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            setTimeout(function(){ 
            window.open("http://www.google.com")}, 5000);
        });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186574/load-a-url-after-a-specific-amount-of-time

Comment: user3450475 has nailed it, you want a pop-up, g good pop-up blocker will block that.  Perhaps you could open the window when the user clicks a link and apply the 5 second delay server-side.

Comment: @Zeeshan i do the same

Comment: @JonathanLonowski you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"
  }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

unblock pop up for your browser

Comment: how can I ask all the visitors to do the same

Comment: display a message to ask user to unblock?

Answer (score -1):

```
function open_win() {
    window.open("x.com");
    setTimeout("window.open('y.com')",60000);
    setTimeout("window.open('z.com')",120000);
}
```

This should open x.com then after one minute y.com and after two it should open z.com.
If still there is a pop-up error, check this question's answer: [Bypass popup blocker on window.open when JQuery event.preventDefault() is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514698/bypass-popup-blocker-on-window-open-when-jquery-event-preventdefault-is-set).

Comment: Passing a string to `setTimeout()` to eval is rarely ever a good idea.

Comment: For the newbies, it seems to be the simplest way to get it out.

Comment: Have you gone through that link? Or should I repost here?